# animationDrawable is not playing in Actionbar?

Tags: android

I am using the developer guide (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html) to create a animating record button, Making minor changes to accomadate an actionbar menuitem instead of an imageView. When I call the onStart it does not play?

Here is the code im using

```
RecordButton.setIcon(R.drawable.recordbutton);
recordAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) RecordButton.getIcon();
recordAnimation.start();
```

Does anyone know why its not playing?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem. My icon changes to the AnimationDrawable, but stays stuck on the first frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I was able to get around it by using an action bar provider as described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider

Skip the ShareActionProvider and create a custom one. This lets you use a custom layout for your action bar item (an ImageView in this case) that you can manipulate as described in your link to the Drawable Animation guide.

Comment: To follow up on this for anyone else needing something similar to what I did. I wanted the menu item to act like a normal item but with the animated icon. To get the item to behave normally, I had to add a few extra things: [Making the tooltip/toast appear on long press](http://pastebin.com/sHjM1mep), and [Making the menu item focusable](http://pastebin.com/NMJTf6CE) (highlights when pressed or selected with arrow keys).

Answer (score 2):

for me working call **start()** in next *cycle*

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        animationDrawable.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm telling this for someone that might end up here: in my app I just tried changing an icon of a button of the ActionBar with an AnimationDrawable with the same method and it works.

---

My AnimationDrawable `ic_action_recording_active`:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_recording_active0" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_recording_active1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_recording_active2" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

I call this method after pressing on the icon (I handle them in the `onOptionsItemSelected`):

```
public void changeMenuIcon(MenuItem item) {
    if (isRecording) {
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_recording_active);
        AnimationDrawable icon = (AnimationDrawable) item.getIcon();
        icon.start();
    } else {
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_recording);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I just saw that using `icon.start()` in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` doensn't actually start the animation...

I ended up calling `changeMenuIcon` in the `onWindowFocusChanged`