# Android: animation in action bar does not work with async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-animation

**Goal**: To have a connect icon in the action bar. OnClick, it should try to connect in the background. While it is trying to connect, the connection animation should play. It should then switch back to "not_connected" or "connected" drawable, depending on success or failure.

**Problem**: If I call the code inside the onClick method of the Custom Action Provider, it works perfectly (see commented-out portion that toggles it). When the same exact code is inside onPreExecute of the AsyncTask, it will not play (it stays on the first frame), even though I am passing a reference to the ImageView.

**My setup**: To do a Frame Animation in the action bar, you have to use a Custom Action Provider (see [animationDrawable is not playing in Actionbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940472/animationdrawable-is-not-playing-in-actionbar)). So, I have a custom layout, a Custom Action Provider that inflates it and sets up the on-click method. My connection functionality is inside an AsyncTask so that it will connect asynchronously.

**Any ideas?**

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/connect"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/btn_connect"
        android:actionProviderClass="com.****.ConnectIconActionProvider"
        />
</menu>
```

layout/connecting_animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ivConnecting"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_not_connected" />
```

anim/connectinganimation.xml

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_connecting1" android:duration="300" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_connecting2" android:duration="300" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_connecting3" android:duration="300" />
</animation-list>
```

ConnectIconActionProvider.java

```
public class ConnectIconActionProvider extends ActionProvider {

    private Context context;
    private ImageView button; 
//  boolean toggle = false;
    private AnimationDrawable animationDrawable;

    public ConnectIconActionProvider(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateActionView(MenuItem forItem) {

        // Inflate the action view to be shown on the action bar.
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.connecting_animation, null);
        button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivConnecting);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyClass.toggleConnectionToDevice(button);

//              if (toggle) {
//                  button.setImageResource(R.anim.connectinganimation);
//                  animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) button.getDrawable();
//                  animationDrawable.start();
//              } else {
//                  button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_not_connected);
//                  if (animationDrawable != null) {
//                      animationDrawable.stop();
//                  }
//              }
//              toggle ^= true;
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

MyClass.toggleConnectionToDevice

```
public void toggleConnectionToDevice(ImageView iv) {
    if (deviceConnected) {
        (new DisconnectProgressBar(this, iv)).execute();
    } else {
        (new ConnectProgressBar(this, iv)).execute();
    }
}
```

ConnectProgressBar.java

```
public class ConnectProgressBar extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private final MainActivity activity;
    private AnimationDrawable animationDrawable;
    private ImageView iv;
    private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    public ConnectProgressBar(final MainActivity activity, final ImageView iv) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.iv = iv;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (iv != null) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.anim.connectinganimation);
            animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
            animationDrawable.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
        // Connect to Car
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                activity.isCurrentlyConnecting = true;
                activity.connect(); 
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void result) {
        if (activity.deviceConnected) {         
            // Show Connected Icon
            if (animationDrawable != null) {
                animationDrawable.stop();
            }
            if (iv != null) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_connected);
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Connect failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Show Disconnected Icon
            if (animationDrawable != null) {
                animationDrawable.stop();
            }
            if (iv != null) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_not_connected);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue with my initial block of code. The handler is running on the UI thread, so it blocks the UI thread from updating.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            activity.isCurrentlyConnecting = true;
            activity.connect(); 
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up scrapping the custom action provider and animation xml. I am just doing it manually with a timer inside of my AsyncTask. It might not be as "correct", but it's definitely simpler.

```
public class ConnectProgressBar extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private final MainActivity activity;
    private MenuItem item;
    private Timer timer;

    public ConnectProgressBar(final MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        startAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
        // Connect to Car
        activity.connectHardware();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void result) {
        stopAnimation();

        if (myClass.deviceConnected) {
            // Show Connected Icon
            if (item != null) {
                setIcon(R.drawable.ic_connected);
                setTitle(R.string.btn_disconnect);
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Connect failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Show Disconnected Icon
            if (item != null) {
                setIcon(R.drawable.ic_not_connected);
                setTitle(R.string.btn_connect);
            }
        }

    }

    private void startAnimation() {
        if (timer == null) {
            timer = new Timer();
        }
        timer.schedule(new AnimateTask(), 0, 300);
    }

    private class AnimateTask extends TimerTask {
        int frame = 0;

        AnimateTask() {
            if (item == null) {
                item = activity.myMenu.findItem(R.id.connect);
            }
            if (item != null) {
                setTitle(R.string.btn_connecting);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Animate!
            switch (frame % 3) {
            case 0:
                setIcon(R.drawable.ic_connecting1);
                break;
            case 1:
                setIcon(R.drawable.ic_connecting2);
                break;
            case 2:
                setIcon(R.drawable.ic_connecting3);
                break;
            }
            frame++;
        }
    }

    private void setIcon(final int resId) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                item.setIcon(resId);
            }
        });
    }
    private void setTitle(final int resId) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                item.setTitle(resId);
            }
        });
    }
    private void stopAnimation() {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}
```